# stubbed cassandra for data storage

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-cli

I need an embedded cassandra for my project and I was wondering if I can use Stubbed Cassandra for data storage. Because I need a system to simulate CQL requests and responses.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use it as a real datastore. Use real cassandra as a real cassandra datastore. check out [ccm](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) which is probably more what your looking for.

There are wrappers for it in [dtests](https://github.com/riptano/cassandra-dtest) (python) and the java driver uses it for testing and has [a java wrapper](https://github.com/tfredrich/cassandra-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/core/CCMBridge.java).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have any experience at all with SCassandra but I worked on several projects using Apache Cassandra and there are some use cases like multidatacenter infrastructure to experiment and I don't think SCassandra can do it. So if you plan to do simple tests, that's fine, But advanced use cases really need to be tested in a real cassandra distribution.

Comment: I am not planning to use scassandra for testing but as a local system to store my data. Is that possible ? Or it offers only testing methods ?

Comment: Which kind of data do you plan to store? I ask it because there can be other databases taylored for your needs. Do you plan to use it in production? According to the docs, `Stubbed Cassandra is an open source tool that enables you to test applications that use Cassandra in a quick, deterministic way. It is especially aimed edge case testing such as read and write timeouts.`. My guess is that it's only for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes, I understand that scassandra was designed for testing purpose. But, I want to use as a real cassandra to store data in a local machine. I don't know if that is possible. I don't want to reinstall cassandra in my machine and configure it, i want to make a use of scassandra since it runs an instance of cassandra without any installation

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you will need the real Cassandra for data storage. However, if you want to test CQL requests/responses then you can use this library:

- [Cassandra-Spy](http://github.com/ajermakovics/cassandra-spy)

It runs an actual embedded Cassandra and also can simulate failures for inserts/selects. This helps you test your app's behaviour in failure cases. I wrote the library to address this specific use case.